# SQL Server Export To Excel 2010 bigger 255 character

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm trying to export a SQL server table to an Excel `.xlsx` file, but when bigger 255 character row, I get an error:

> **Error 0xc0202009:** Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code **DTS_E_OLEDBERROR**. An OLE DB error has occurred.
>
> Error code: 0x00040EDA.
>   An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft Office Access Database Engine"
>   Hresult: 0x80040E21
>   Description: "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data.".

Could you share any recommendation about fixing this problem?

Comment: Are you obliged to use an .xlsx? You could use an .xls or .csv and not encounter this problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer @alex.I know .xls format working clearly,but i am curious why not work that .xlsx format.